# Load offline images stored in iPhone

Tags: ios, image, core-data, storage

I have to build an iPhone app that every X days has an online sync with a web service, it downloads X images and saves them into the device.

Then, in offline mode, I have to load the images on a table view.

I was thinking about the Core Data storage, is that possible? Maybe storing images in core data database will slow down the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried something similar but found Core Data unsuitable. If I were you I would keep the references to the images in CD but store the images themselves as they are.

Comment: That's good for the image reference, but I have to store them on the device already, because I have to show in the offline mode. Any suggestion about how and where to save them?